# Como registrar o logout do usuário quando ele fecha o navegador ou uma aba dele?

Tags: php, jquery

Estou criando uma aplicação web e preciso registrar o login e logout do usuário em uma tabela do banco de dados.

Fiz tudo certo, está registrando o login (quando o usuário loga) e o logout (quando o usuário fecha o sistema no botão).

Porém, quando o usuário fecha uma aba do navegador ou o navegador por inteiro, o registro do logout não é feito.

Tentei uma solução que vi aqui no Stack, utilizando o unload,mas não deu certo.

**Tentei esse código abaixo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).unload(function() {


    $.ajax({
      url: "../banco/validador-de-login/logout.php",
      type: "POST",



    }).done(function(data) {



    }).fail(function() {


    }).always(function() {


    });


  });


});
```

Comment: Você quer isso para fins de rateabilidade ou para garantir o login quando usuário voltar outro dia. pois talvez caiba o uso de globais $_SESSION, ao invés do usp do banco desta forma.

Comment: É só para ter um registro de quando o usuário logou e deslogou do sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, consegui uma solução (com um amigo) que pode ser útil pra muitas pessoas que desejam fazer algo parecido.

Eu usei o ***window.onbeforeunload = function(){}*** que executa a função quando fechamos o navegador.

E também, ao invés de usar ajax, etc... Eu usei o $.get para chamar o arquivo que registra o logout.

**O código JS ficou assim:**

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.get("../banco/validador-de-login/logout.php", function(data) {
    return false;
  });
}
```

Obrigado!